# How to get indices of N minimum values per row in a NumPy matrix with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have the following NumPy matrix:

```
m = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [10, 5, 3, 4],
              [12, 8, 1, 2],
              [7, 0, 2, 4]])
```

Now, I need the indices of N (say, N=2) lowest values of each row in this matrix . So with the example above, I expect the following output:

```
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [3, 2],
 [1, 2]]
```

where the rows of the output matrix correspond to the respective rows of the original, and the elements of the rows of the output matrix are the indices of the N lowest values in the corresponding original rows (preferably in ascending order by values in the original matrix). How could I do it in NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use a simple loop-approach (not recommended) or you use [`np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
In [13]: np.argpartition(m, 2)[:, :2]
Out[13]:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [1, 2]])
```

Comment: Sorry, what is "2" as the second parameter of argpartition?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [np.argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on your array and then slice the array with the amount of N lowest/highest values.

```
np.argsort(m, axis=1)[:, :2]
```

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [10, 5, 3, 4],
              [12, 8, 1, 2],
              [7, 0, 2, 4]])

for arr in m:
    print(arr.argsort()[:2])
```